# What does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt n(n+1)}$ converge to exactly?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt n(n+1)}=S,$$

does $S$ have a known closed-form symbolic expression for its value? By the integral test it clearly converges, i.e. take $u=\sqrt x$ and $u$-substitute to get

$$\int_1^\infty\frac1{\sqrt x(x+1)}dx=2\arctan(\sqrt x)\rvert_1^\infty=\frac\pi2.$$

The sum was also in a competition problem, or so I'm told, to show that $S<2$ (if a source for this problem can be found, I'd appreciate it).

Comment: What do you mean with "closed form" your serie is clearly convergent, so it is a positive number.

How to calculate it, is another problem.

Comment: Alright, I've fixed the question. I don't know if I'm asking it precisely enough though. Any suggestions on wording? "Symbolic expression" is a bit vague, since sums are also symbolic expressions.

Comment: The serie is convergent, That menas that OF COURSE you can. 
So your question should be "How to COMPUTE this number?" I think.

Comment: To the OP: I think closed form is exactly the expression you are looking for

Comment: Mathematica doesn't know a closed form for this series

Comment: I think it is clear what the OP means by closed form.

Comment: It's $(n+1)\sqrt{n} $, right, not $\sqrt{n(n+1)}$? Just asking because in the MathJax code you are not using `{}` to enclose $n$...

Comment: Yeah, the expression as given is what I'm asking. I just like taking shortcuts in code.

Comment: Maple also doesn't know a closed form.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TheodorussConstant.html

Comment: However, you could transform it to $$ \frac{1}{2} - \sum_{j=1}^\infty (-1)^j \left(\zeta\left(j+\frac12\right)-1\right)$$

Comment: @Tito: do you understand closed form now? It is commonplace in mathematics to ask if an expression involving a sum or an integral has a closed form (typically in the form of known constants).

Comment: OK, I'm reasonably convinced now that finding a closed form is probably very difficult.

Comment: @Clayton I misunderstood the idea with a previous version of the question (with an indefinite integral or something like this)

Comment: @Tito: looking at the edit history, it appears the question itself is clear: does the sum have a closed form? The OP then explains why it obviously converges (he doesn’t calculate the integral explicitly, but gives the indefinite integral). Even by your first comment, it appears that you didn’t understand what it meant to ask for a closed form (saying calculating the value of a sum is a different question when it is, in fact, exactly the same question).

Comment: Have you considered applying the Euler-Maclaurin Summation Formula?

Comment: Show that $S<2$, possible.  Find closed form for $S$, impossible.

Comment: You (accidentally?) delivered a very nice exercise: by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, the series $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{(n+1)\sqrt{n}}$ turns out to be extremely close to $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}\sqrt{3}=\color{green}{1.860}35\ldots$. I ask your permission to include it in the first section of [my notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view).

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I heard this exercise (show the sum is $<2$) was in some math contest, but unfortunately I don't have a source. So, I guess, feel free to use it as you wish, but I'm not sure my permission is relevant here ahaha.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While I doubt there's a closed form, we can get a double integral easily enough:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^\infty e^{-n x^2} dx$$

$$\frac{1}{n+1}= \int_0^\infty e^{-(n+1) y} dy$$

Then the general term will be:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}(n+1)}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-y} e^{-n (x^2+y)} ~dx ~dy$$

Let's try exchanging the summation and integration:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n (x^2+y)}=\frac{1}{e^{x^2+y}-1}$$

Now we need the integral to converge, otherwise this whole thing would be in vain.

Numerically, using Mathematica, we have:

$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-y}}{e^{x^2+y}-1}  ~dx ~dy=1.8600250788 \dots$$

Which is quite in good agreement with the numerical value obtained for the series itself (the OEIS gives $1.86002507922119\dots$).

So, we can claim:

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt n(n+1)}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-y}}{e^{x^2+y}-1}  ~dx ~dy$$

Why didn't I try to get a single integral? Because in that case after summation under the integral sign I got only divergent integrals.

**Edit:**

From the [OEIS link](http://oeis.org/A226317) we can actually see that the single integral also works. That's what I tried (only using my first integral and summing up the result with $1/(n+1)$, but I thought that the resulting integral of $$\int_0^\infty (-1-e^{x^2} \log (1-e^{-x^2}))dx$$ diverged. Apparently it doesn't.

**Edit 2:**

Let's try to make my double integral a little prettier.

$$\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-y}}{e^{x^2+y}-1}  ~dx ~dy=2\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{z~e^{-z^2}}{e^{x^2+z^2}-1}  ~dx ~dz=$$

$$x=r \cos t \\ z= r \sin t$$

$$=2\int_0^\infty \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{r^2 \sin t~e^{-r^2 \sin^2 t}}{e^{r^2}-1}  ~dt ~dr= \\ =2\int_0^\infty \int_0^1 \frac{r^2 e^{-r^2} e^{r^2 u^2}}{e^{r^2}-1}  ~du ~dr=\sqrt{\pi} \int_0^\infty \frac{r ~\text{erfi}(r) e^{-r^2}}{e^{r^2}-1}  ~dr$$

This integral converges very well and we get:

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt n(n+1)}=2 \int_0^\infty \frac{r ~\text{erfi}(r) e^{-r^2}}{e^{r^2}-1}  ~dr$$

Mathematica easily gives 50 correct digits of the series:

```
In[71]:= NIntegrate[
 2 u Erfi[u] Exp[-u^2]/(Exp[u^2] - 1), {u, 0, Infinity}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 50]

Out[71]= 1.8600250792211903071806959157171433246665241215235
```

Or we can rewrite this in a slightly shorter form:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt n(n+1)}=\int_0^\infty \frac{\text{erfi}(\sqrt{r}) e^{-r}}{e^{r}-1}  ~dr$$

---

We can also generalize the above to:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt n(n+a)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\int_0^\infty \frac{\text{erfi}(\sqrt{ar}) e^{-ar}}{e^{r}-1}  ~dr$$

Taking the limit for $a \to 0$, we recover the well known integral for the zeta function $\zeta(3/2)$.

---

**Edit 3:**

I'm sorry for bloating this post, but I wanted to make a few notes about numerical integration of the obtained expression.

It can be easily done by Gauss-Laguerre quadrature, provided we remove the singularity near $r=0$. Which can be done by getting the asymptotic expression as $r \to 0$:

$$\frac{\text{erfi}(\sqrt{r})}{e^{r}-1} \to \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi r}}-\frac{\sqrt{r}}{3\sqrt{\pi}}+\frac{r^{3/2}}{30\sqrt{\pi}}+\frac{r^{5/2}}{315\sqrt{\pi}}+\dots$$

This singularity is exactly integrable and so we can write:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\text{erfi}(\sqrt{r}) }{e^{r}-1}  e^{-r}~dr=2-\int_0^\infty 
  \left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi r}}-\frac{\text{erfi}(\sqrt{r}) }{e^{r}-1} \right) e^{-r}~dr$$

This allows us to approximate the integrand near $0$ by a well defined series:

$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{r}}-\sqrt{\pi} \frac{\text{erfi}(\sqrt{r})}{e^{r}-1}= \\ =\sqrt{r} \left(3-\frac{r}{30}-\frac{r^2}{315} +\frac{r^3}{1512}+\frac{r^4}{13860}-\frac{521 r^5}{32432400}-\frac{29 r^6}{16216200}+\dots \right) $$

The terms shown give the absolute error of the order $10^{-11}$ at $r=1/4$.

So we can denote:

$$f(r)=\frac{\sqrt{r}}{\sqrt{\pi}} \left(3-\frac{r}{30}-\frac{r^2}{315} +\frac{r^3}{1512}+\frac{r^4}{13860}-\frac{521 r^5}{32432400}-\frac{29 r^6}{16216200} \right) $$

And write:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt n(n+1)} \approx 2-\int_0^{1/4} 
  f(r) e^{-r}~dr-\int_{1/4}^\infty 
  \left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi r}}-\frac{\text{erfi}(\sqrt{r}) }{e^{r}-1} \right) e^{-r}~dr$$

The first integral can taken exactly in terms of error function, while the second can be approximated by Gauss-Laguerre quadrature with very good accuracy.

Provided both the integrals above are computed with high enough precision, we get absolute error of the order $10^{-12}$ when compared to the numerical value for the series.

This also agrees with the bound from @robjohn's answer.

Not very convenient, but at least I have shown how to use this integral if one doesn't have advanced software like Mathematica.

Answer (score 5):

This adds pretty little to the previous answer: the (inverse) Laplace transform allows to write the given series as the integral $\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{F(\sqrt{s})}{e^s-1}\,ds$ where $F$ is Dawson's function. $F(\sqrt{s})$ approximately behaves like $\sqrt{s} e^{-2s/3}$ and any algorithm for numerical integration is able to provide a decent approximation for the mentioned integral.

This actually brings something new to the table: by hand, me may realize that
$$ \color{red}{S}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{(n+1)\sqrt{n}} \color{red}{\approx} \frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\pi}\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{4^n(n+1)}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{4}\sqrt{\pi}}$$
since $\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\approx\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$ is a  pretty good approximation for any $n\geq 1$ and the generating function for Catalan numbers is fairly well-known. This can be improved by exploting the more accurate
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\approx\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\left(1+\tfrac{1}{8n}+\tfrac{1}{128n(n+2)}\right).$$

Creative telescoping also deserves a try: indeed, $\frac{1}{(n+1)\sqrt{n}}<\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{n+1}}$ immediately proves $\color{red}{S<2}$, and the more accurate $\frac{1}{(n+1)\sqrt{n}}\approx \frac{2}{\sqrt{n+\frac{1}{6}}}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{n+\frac{7}{6}}}$ gives $\color{red}{S\approx \frac{1}{2}+2\sqrt{\frac{6}{13}}}$.

> We may also combine the approximation through central binomial coefficients with the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to get an exceptionally simple and very accurate approximation:
>   $$ S\leq \frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\left(\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{4^n}{n(n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}\right)\left(\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{(n+1)4^n}\right)}=\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{\pi^2}{4}\cdot\frac{3}{4}}$$
>   gives $\color{red}{S\approx \frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\pi}$, whose absolute error is less than $4\cdot 10^{-4}$.

Answer (score 4):

**Less than $\boldsymbol{2}$**

Since $n+1\gt\frac12\left(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}\right)\sqrt{n+1}$ ,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{\sqrt{n\vphantom{1}}\,(n+1)}
&\lt\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac2{\sqrt{n\vphantom{1}}\,\sqrt{n+1}\left(\sqrt{n\vphantom{1}}+\sqrt{n+1}\right)}\\
&=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{\sqrt{n\vphantom{1}}}-\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}\right)\\[6pt]
&=2\tag1
\end{align}
$$

---

**Numerical Value**

The Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula gives
$$
\scriptsize\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt{k}\,(k+1)}=2\arctan\left(\sqrt{n}\right)+C-\pi+\frac1{2\sqrt{n}\,(n+1)}-\frac{3n+1}{24n^{3/2}(n+1)^2}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^{7/2}}\right)\tag2
$$
but we can handle this a bit easier if we expand the summand into a power series.
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{n}\,(n+1)}=\sum_{k=0}^{11}\frac{(-1)^k}{n^{k+3/2}}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^{27/2}}\right)\tag3
$$
and apply the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula to $(3)$ to get
$$
\begin{align}
\scriptsize\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt{k}\,(k+1)}
&\scriptsize=C-\frac2{n^{1/2}}+\frac7{6\,n^{3/2}}-\frac{41}{40\,n^{5/2}}+\frac{167}{168\,n^{7/2}}-\frac{1147}{1152\,n^{9/2}}\\
&\scriptsize+\frac{1411}{1408\,n^{11/2}}-\frac{200201}{199680\,n^{13/2}}+\frac{15331}{15360\,n^{15/2}}-\frac{1665833}{1671168\,n^{17/2}}\\[6pt]
&\scriptsize+\frac{4371365}{4358144\,n^{19/2}}-\frac{83113379}{82575360\,n^{21/2}}+\frac{89747287}{90439680\,n^{23/2}}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^{25/2}}\right)\tag4
\end{align}
$$
where
$$
\scriptsize C=1.8600250792211903071806959157171433246665241215234514930491995\tag5
$$
$C$ was computed by summing the first $100000$ terms and using the series in $(4)$ evaluated at $n=100000$. Thus,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{\sqrt{n}\,(n+1)}=C\tag6
$$

Answer (score 4):

To add still more less-than-closed forms, it can be also thought of in terms of integration of de Jonquiere's polylogarithm, $\mathrm{Li}_s(z)$. In particular, this function is defined by

$$\mathrm{Li}_s(z) := \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n^s}$$

Clearly one can see that

$$\int_{0}^{z} \mathrm{Li}_s(u)\ du = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^{n+1}}{n^s (n+1)} = z \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n^s (n+1)}$$

and if you take $z = 1$ and $s = \frac{1}{2}$, you have the desired sum, that is,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}(n+1)} = \int_{0}^{1} \mathrm{Li}_\frac{1}{2}(t)\ dt$$

Sadly, the polylogarithm of fractional order does not integrate into anything else and Wolfram says it "has no expression in terms of standard mathematical functions".